# ListView binding itemsource with a list of visuals

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I'm trying to create a binding on a listView with itemssource as a list of objects that inherits of Canvas.

Example :

```
ObservableCollection<MountainSki> msList = new ObservableCollection<MountainSki>();

MountainSki ms = new MountainSki("La Clusaz");

msList.add(ms);

myListView.ItemsSource = msList;
```

But when I run the programm, i have an argumentexception. Some advices ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Post error message / stack trace and inner exception if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a listView, all the items have for parent the listView. In your case, the elements in the ObservableCollection may already have a parent.

You should refactor your code to respect the MVVM architecture.